# Algorithm for finding first repeated substring of length k

Tags: algorithm, string, data-structures, hash, substring

There is a homework I should do and I need help. I should write a program to find the first substring of length k that is repeated in the string at least twice.

For example in the string "banana" there are two repeated substrings of length 2: "an" , "na". In this case, the answer is "an" because it appeared sooner than "na"

**Note that the simple O(n^2) algorithm is not useful since there is time limit on execution time of program so I guess it should be in linear time.**

There is a hint too: Use Hash table.

I don't want the code.  I just want you to give me a clue because I have no idea how to do this using a hash table. Should I use a specific data structure too?

Comment: Which language are you coding in?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Iterate over the character indexes of the string (0, 1, 2, ...) up to and including the index of the second-from-last character (i.e. up to strlen(str) - 2).  For each iteration, do the following...

Extract the 2-char substring starting at the character index.

Check whether your hashtable contains the 2-char substring.  If it does, you've got your answer.

Insert each 2-char substring into the hashtable.

This is easily modifiable to cope with substrings of length k.

Comment: calculating hash function is O(k) and by iterating over the characters of strings the execution time of algorithm would be O(nk) or O(n^2) and that's a lot of time! Thanks for reply anyway

Comment: O(nk) isn't O(n^2) - k bears no relation to the length of the string being searched.  I can certainly see where you're coming from with that argument, though.  I'll assert that there is no (significantly) better way of doing this with a hash table.

Comment: 1<k<n so can't we tell k = n-c ( c is some constant and we know there is such constant for every K ) and then conclude that O(nk) = O( n(n-c) ) = O(n^2 - nc) = O(n^2)? Can you explain what's wrong with this conclusion?

Comment: @omid: `k` in your task is a constant, that is, it doesn't depend on string length `n`. So, you can not write that `k = n - c`, since `n` can change and complexity will stay the same. For example, if calculation for string of length 10 takes 100 msec, calculation for string of 20 chars will take 200 msec (n * 2) not 400 msec ((n * 2)^2). So, `k` doesn't change time complexity. Nevertheless, it's worth to mention, that in _some_ tasks substring length `k` _may_ affect time complexity.

Comment: ffriend and Will A : you're right. you'r trying to say:              nk is not theta(n^2) and that's right, but it IS O(n^2). However the important thing in my case is theta not O

Answer (score 3):

Combine Will A's algorithm with a [rolling hash](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rolling_hash) to get a linear-time algorithm.

Comment: Also, omid, you're right: any function that is O(n k) is also O(n^2), since O (in the tradition of Knuth) is for upper bounds. ffriend is right, however, that n k is a significant improvement on n^2 for small k.

Answer (score 0):

You can use linked hash map.

```java
public static String findRepeated(String s , int k){
    Map<String,Integer> map = new LinkedHashMap<String,Integer>();
    for(int i = 0 ; i < s.length() - k ; i ++){
        String temp = s.substring(i,i +k);
        if(!map.containsKey(temp)){
            map.put(temp, 1);
        }
        else{
            map.put(temp, map.get(temp) + 1);
        }
    }
    for(Map.Entry<String,Integer> entry : map.entrySet()){
        if(entry.getValue() > 1){
            return entry.getKey();
        }
    }
    return "no such value";
}
```